# Translating a specific Promise from Javascript to Python

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to translate this piece of code from Javascript to Python but could not find an equivalent of a Promise and an async function in Python.

```
async function sendRequest(options) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error)
            resolve({
                response: response,
                body: body
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: what has been your current attempt now? python has an `async` keyword you can use it like `async def func_name()`

Comment: For the async function, I thought of using async as well but was not sure it would return the exact same output that Javascript would. For the concept of making a Promise in Javascript, I have no clue how to find a Python equivalent to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for python's [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). The high-level equivalent of a javascript `Promise` is an [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables). Since you want to return an awaitable from a function, you should use the `async` keyword to return a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines), which is a type of awaitable.

As for making an async http request, I would recommend [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

It sounds like this might be some sort of assignment, so I'm not going to fill in all the blanks for you, but the aiohttp link I provided has plenty of good examples and comprehensive docs that you can dig into. The below is a template for you to work from:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

# this function returns a coroutine, which must be awaited
# elsewhere. you can use return statements normally within its
# body, but be aware that those will be returned from the
# coroutine once it has been awaited, not directly from
# send_request
async def send_request(options):
    # do stuff with aiohttp...

# this is how to call from synchronous code
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(send_request())

# this is how to call from within another async function
async def foo():
    await send_request(options)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks

Comment: Sure thing. Please remember to upvote and accept answers that provide useful information pertaining to your question (I know you can't upvote yet, but you can accept). This allows future users with the same question to quickly see which answers are the most helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "you can accept"? How would I do that?

Comment: See the little checkmark on the left next to the answer's voting spinner (the up/down arrows)? Click that, and it will turn green, indicating that you've accepted the answer as correct. [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/ccdsmAK) a screencap of an accepted and upvoted answer for reference.

Comment: Ok, I did it, thanks